# Lexicaljs editor clicking image is not triggering node selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, facebook, lexicaljs

I have created custom `ImageNode` by extending the `DecoratorNode`.

When I click the ImageNode,

a click event is fired on the `span` of that node as expected,

but still `selection.getNodes()` doesn't have the image node.

while clicking on other elements works fine.

Here is the implementation of `ImageNode`

```
import type {
    DOMConversionMap,
    DOMConversionOutput,
    DOMExportOutput,
    EditorConfig,
    LexicalEditor,
    LexicalNode,
    NodeKey,
    SerializedEditor,
    SerializedLexicalNode,
    Spread,
} from "lexical";

import { createEditor, DecoratorNode } from "lexical";

import ImageComponent from "./ImageComponent";

export interface ImagePayload {
    altText: string;
    caption?: LexicalEditor;
    height: number;
    key?: NodeKey;
    maxWidth?: number;
    showCaption?: boolean;
    src: string;
    width: number;
    captionsEnabled?: boolean;
}

function convertImageElement(domNode: Node): null | DOMConversionOutput {
    if (domNode instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
        const { alt: altText, src } = domNode;
        const node = $createImageNode({
            altText,
            src,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
        });
        return { node };
    }
    return null;
}

export type SerializedImageNode = Spread<
    {
        altText: string;
        caption: SerializedEditor;
        height: number;
        maxWidth: number;
        showCaption: boolean;
        src: string;
        width: number;
        type: "image";
        version: 1;
    },
    SerializedLexicalNode
>;

export class ImageNode
    extends DecoratorNode<JSX.Element>
    implements LexicalNode
{
    __src: string;
    __altText: string;
    __width: number;
    __height: number;
    __maxWidth: number;
    __showCaption: boolean;
    __caption: LexicalEditor;
    // Captions cannot yet be used within editor cells
    __captionsEnabled: boolean;

    static getType(): string {
        return "image";
    }

    static clone(node: ImageNode): ImageNode {
        return new ImageNode(
            node.__src,
            node.__altText,
            node.__maxWidth,
            node.__width,
            node.__height,
            node.__showCaption,
            node.__caption,
            node.__captionsEnabled,
            node.__key
        );
    }

    static importJSON(serializedNode: SerializedImageNode): ImageNode {
        const { altText, height, width, maxWidth, caption, src, showCaption } =
            serializedNode;
        const node = $createImageNode({
            altText,
            height,
            maxWidth,
            showCaption,
            src,
            width,
        });
        const nestedEditor = node.__caption;
        const editorState = nestedEditor.parseEditorState(caption.editorState);
        if (!editorState.isEmpty()) {
            nestedEditor.setEditorState(editorState);
        }
        return node;
    }

    exportDOM(): DOMExportOutput {
        const element = document.createElement("img");
        element.setAttribute("src", this.__src);
        element.setAttribute("alt", this.__altText);
        return { element };
    }

    static importDOM(): DOMConversionMap | null {
        return {
            img: (node: Node) => ({
                conversion: convertImageElement,
                priority: 0,
            }),
        };
    }

    constructor(
        src: string,
        altText: string,
        maxWidth: number,
        width: number,
        height: number,
        showCaption?: boolean,
        caption?: LexicalEditor,
        captionsEnabled?: boolean,
        key?: NodeKey
    ) {
        super(key);
        this.__src = src;
        this.__altText = altText;
        this.__maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.__width = width ?? 300;
        this.__height = height ?? 300;
        this.__showCaption = showCaption || false;
        this.__caption = caption || createEditor();
        this.__captionsEnabled =
            captionsEnabled || captionsEnabled === undefined;
    }

    exportJSON(): SerializedImageNode {
        return {
            altText: this.getAltText(),
            caption: this.__caption.toJSON(),
            height: this.__height,
            maxWidth: this.__maxWidth,
            showCaption: this.__showCaption,
            src: this.getSrc(),
            type: "image",
            version: 1,
            width: this.__width,
        };
    }

    setWidthAndHeight(width: number, height: number): void {
        const writable = this.getWritable();
        writable.__width = width;
        writable.__height = height;
    }

    setShowCaption(showCaption: boolean): void {
        const writable = this.getWritable();
        writable.__showCaption = showCaption;
    }

    // View

    createDOM(config: EditorConfig): HTMLElement {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        const theme = config.theme;
        const className = theme.image;
        if (className !== undefined) {
            span.className = className;
        }
        return span;
    }

    updateDOM(): false {
        return false;
    }

    getSrc(): string {
        return this.__src;
    }

    getAltText(): string {
        return this.__altText;
    }

    decorate(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <ImageComponent
                src={this.__src}
                altText={this.__altText}
                width={this.__width}
                height={this.__height}
                maxWidth={this.__maxWidth}
                nodeKey={this.__key}
                showCaption={this.__showCaption}
                caption={this.__caption}
                captionsEnabled={this.__captionsEnabled}
                resizable={true}
            />
        );
    }
}

export function $createImageNode({
    altText,
    height,
    maxWidth = 500,
    captionsEnabled,
    src,
    width,
    showCaption,
    caption,
    key,
}: ImagePayload): ImageNode {
    return new ImageNode(
        src,
        altText,
        maxWidth,
        width,
        height,
        showCaption,
        caption,
        captionsEnabled,
        key
    );
}

export function $isImageNode(
    node: LexicalNode | null | undefined
): node is ImageNode {
    return node instanceof ImageNode;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found what the problem were?